# Samsung J3 2016 (SM-J320F) is lost

Tags: lost-phone

My son as just lost his phone yesterday. I have tried using find my phone but it's only coming up with a serial number. 
not the phone number. Is that because someone as taking the SIM card out and using a different one and if so can I track the card that they have put in it. I need to find it cause we can't afford to buy him a new one. Please help someone.

Comment: This is unfortunate. If the phone is lost and no number is present, this can mean anything and nothing. Not all SIM cards report the phone number to the system, but Find My Phone is not tied to a phone number, it's tied to the serial number of the device. My advice: Go to the police, report it as stolen and ask them to locate it (bring the box with all the numbers like IMEI, serial number, proof of ownership/receipt). They can help you to get it back.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have reported it online as that's what they said do. The number I'm getting on find my mobile is apparently the serial number.